# В чём ошибка при вычислении выражения?

Tags: python, математика

Решаю задания и попалось такое.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал код, но он выводит не те значения, которые указаны в результате работы, когда прогоняю его на входных данных.

```
import math
import sys


arr = list()
for line in sys.stdin:
    x = float(line.rstrip())
    f = math.sin(x) + math.sqrt((math.log(3 * x, 4))) + 3 * math.e ** x
    arr.append(f)

for i in arr:
    print(f'{i:.6f}')

input:
1
2.3
2.56
7.123456

output:

9.886531
31.848633
40.569471
3724.424013
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть ошибка? Есть ли тут вероятность погрешности? Или же всё таки это ошибка сайта?

Comment: Вы на скобочки вокруг экспоненты обратили внимание? На функцию *потолок*, она же *ceil*? Кстати, и экспоненты обычно вычисляют с использованием готовой функции *exp*...

Comment: @Harry нет, не обратил, потому что понятия не имею, что эти скобки значат. Спасибо большое, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math
import sys

arr = list()
for line in sys.stdin:
    x = float(line.rstrip())
    f = math.sin(x) + math.sqrt((math.log(3 * x, 4))) + 3 * math.ceil(math.exp(x))
    arr.append(f)

for i in arr:
    print(f'{i:.6f}')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]